# Node.JS include Jade file errno: -2,

Tags: node.js, pug

Error when i try to include file in jade

```
html
    include head.jade
    body
```

```
{
    errno: -2,
    code: "ENOENT",
    syscall: "open",
    path: "/server/layouts/head.jade"
}
```

path is correctly 100%, pls help me to fix this problem!

Comment: Is the path from the root of your disk or the root of your project? Can you verify the path outside of Node? Try `test -f /server/layouts/head.jade; echo $?;` in a shell/terminal (seeing `0` means success).

Comment: Is the path from the root of my disk! response - 0 in your command.
But problem is remaining

Answer (score 1):

Use the `./` notation to ensure you are loading from the current path.

```
html
    include ./head.jade
    body
```

Comment: Does not help(.
Maybe i can set path project, but i don't know how it make in ubuntu(

Comment: Are the two files in the same directory?